# How to install Google Cloud completion in NixOS with Oh-My-Zsh?

Tags: zsh, nixos, oh-my-zsh, google-cloud

Oh-my-zsh has a plugin option (`plugins = (gcloud, ...)`) which allows installing `gcloud` completions.

When I add "gcloud" to `plugins`, I expect that the completion will be sourced during shell initialization, but it doesn't work on NixOS (version 19.03).

How to install gcloud completions on NixOS with oh-my-zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `gcloud` to `programs.zsh.ohMyZsh.plugins`, I found that I had to manually source the completion script. To do this:

Add `pkgs.google-cloud-sdk` to `environment.systemPackages` of your `configuration.nix` file, and then update the zshrc section:

```
programs.zsh.promptInit = ''
  export CLOUD_SDK_HOME="${pkgs.google-cloud-sdk}"
  source "$CLOUD_SDK_HOME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"
'';
```